# React-hook-form with RadixUI primitive (+TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, radix-ui

I wish to use RadixUi Switch component and that it would work within a form that uses react-hook-form.

I tried to declare a variable "active" in parent component with register function. Then I send this variable as props to a intermediary component which will render RadixUI component. In this intermediary component I tried to pass "active" properties onto Switch.Root.
Result is that when I toggle the switch, it's value is not changing.

How can I fix it?

This is parent component code:

```
const FormOne = (): JSX.Element => {

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  const active = register("active");

  const onSubmit = async (data: FieldValues) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form
      className={styles["form-one"]}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
    >
      <MySwitch formRegistration={active} />

      <button>
        <BsCheckSquareFill className='profile-icon' />
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

This is Intermediary component code

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./MySwitch.module.scss";
import * as Switch from "@radix-ui/react-switch";
import { UseFormRegisterReturn } from "react-hook-form";

interface SwitchProps {
  formRegistration: UseFormRegisterReturn;
}

const MySwitch = ({ formRegistration }: SwitchProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div className='flex-align-center space-between'>
      <Switch.Root className={styles["SwitchRoot"]} {...formRegistration}>
        <Switch.Thumb className={styles["SwitchThumb"]} />
      </Switch.Root>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MySwitch;
```